# Detect Changes to Iframe Content

Tags: jquery

if it possible tell if an Iframe content has changed after the page has loaded?

```
$('iframe').on('load' function () {
alert('iframe loaded')
})
```

will only alert once th page has loaded.

```
$('iframe').on('change' function () {
alert('iframe changed')
})
```

is not called if addition content is added to the iframe

Comment: If the iframe is in the same domain, you can use a `MutationObserver`, just as you would for detecting changes to the content of the current page.

Comment: The `change` event only detects when the user has changes an input element.

Answer (score 1):

If the content of the iframe is on the [same domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) as the parent page, or if you have access to the iframed page so you can [set its CORS policy](https://benohead.com/blog/2015/12/07/cross-document-communication-with-iframes/) to allow requests from the parent page, then you can watch for changes to specific elements or use [MutationOberver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch for changes to the iframe's DOM.

If not, then there's no way that I'm aware of to monitor the iframe for changes.